# Use Braintree with Django app in Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, payment, braintree

I want to use `Braintree` in my Django app that's running in Heroku, I made it work locally, but, when I push my app to Heroku, I get an error.

I'm pretty sure that the problem is that I don't import Braintree to my `requirements.txt`, so...

How can I make `Braintree` work in Heroku?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `Braintree` to `requirements.txt`. Something like

```
Braintree==<verson_here>
```

Just append that to `requirements.txt`, you can know what version by running:

```
pip freeze
```

And this, will give you a list of all the external packages that you have installed. An example screenshot:
[image]

Also as a side note, make sure that you add all the things listed when you get your output from `pip freeze`, so that no dependencies are lacking if there are any.